# Why does this function return undefined.property in JS?

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

I am going over the MDN JavaScript guides and am trying to work along with [the example near the bottom of the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling).

```
var car = { make: "Ford", model: "Mustang" };

function dump_props(obj, obj_name) {
   var result = "";
   for (var i in obj) {
      console.log(result += obj_name + "." + i + " = " + obj[i] + "<br>");
   }
   result += "<hr>";
   console.log(result);
}

dump_props(car);
```

I've altered the original code to return console statements but when I put this in JSBin.com, the console returns:

```
"undefined.make = Ford<br>"
"undefined.make = Ford<br>undefined.model = Mustang<br>"
"undefined.make = Ford<br>undefined.model = Mustang<br><hr>"
```

Why the undefined?
Thanks

Comment: basically your `dump_props` function takes two arguments and you're passing only one, so the second one (`obj_name`) is undefined, hence all the undefined prints in there

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function `dump_props(obj, obj_name)` expects a second `obj_name` param. But you are calling it just passing one param:

```
dump_props(car);
```

So, the second one will be `undefined`. I guess this is what you want:

```
var car = { make: "Ford", model: "Mustang" };

function dump_props(obj, obj_name) {
   var result = "";
   obj_name = obj_name || obj.constructor.name; // Get the object name
   for (var i in obj) {
      console.log(result += obj_name + "." + i + " = " + obj[i] + "<br>");
   }
   result += "<hr>";
   console.log(result);
}

dump_props(car);
dump_props(car,"Car"); // Both ways will work
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmftvekf/)

Answer (score 0):

you didnt pass parameter into function 
try

```
dump_props(car,"carclass");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many `arguments` in your dump_props function.

```
var car = { make: "Ford", model: "Mustang" };

function dump_props(obj) {
   var result = "";
   for (var key in obj) {
      console.log(result += key + " = " + obj[key] + "<br>");
   }
   result += "<hr>";
   console.log(result);
}

dump_props(car);
```

Comment: this won't print the class' name, I don't think it's the expected result, a close one though